# Add custom header to web servies call and read it in web services methods

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, soapheader

i want to know if it is possible to add some custom headers to each web services call and then access these custom header from web services methods:

```
eg. soapclient.headers.add("test","valueoftest")

and from web services:

[WebMethod]
public string helloworld()
{
return "Hello world" + getcustomheader

}
```

I need to add header also in ajax calls so i need to know where to add these custom header in javascript:

```
var soapHeader = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap12=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\"><soap12:Body>[body]</soap12:Body></soap12:Envelope>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On client side, you can add custom header using `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader`.For example:

```
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader('Custom', 'MyHeader');
```

On server side:

```
[WebMethod]
public string helloworld()
{
  string customHeader = HttpContext.Current.Request.Header["Custom"];
  return "Hello world" + customHeader;

}
```